# paging an array result in D7

Tags: 7, paging

I have a Query like this:

```
$query = db_select('nid_tid', 'nt')
->fields('nt')
->condition('terms', $name,'=');
$result=$query->execute();

$row=$result->fetchAssoc();
$nid =$row['nid'];
$ex=explode(',', $nid);
foreach ($ex as $tag_nid)
{
  $out .= $tag_nid;
}
```

return $out

I want paging this result .for example per 10 result in one page

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the query to a [`PagerDefault`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/class/PagerDefault/7), and then use [`theme_pager()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) to output the pager links at the end of your content. The rest will be taken care of for you:

```
$limit = 10;
$query = db_select('nid_tid', 'nt')
  ->fields('nt')
  ->condition('terms', $name,'=');

$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($limit);

$result = $query->execute();

$row = $result->fetchAssoc();
$nid = $row['nid'];
$ex = explode(',', $nid);
foreach ($ex as $tag_nid) {
  $out .= $tag_nid;
}

$out .= theme('pager');
```

Comment: hi ,and thank you.this is not working.because my result Always is one,therefore Always num_rows in this query is 1.